# Setting height of (two) JEditorPanes regardless of the font used

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

Is there a way in Java Swing by which we can find the exact possible height needed to display a line of text regardless of the font/font size used?

I an using a `JEditorPane` and I wanted the height to be in sync with another editor pane in the same panel. Basically the  whole idea was to let both the editor panes have same height depending on the text in them.

Note: I have a listener in place which keep changing the height of these two panes based on the text in them, so that if I edit the code in one of these panes and the height becomes greater than the other, the new height (of both the panes) should be the height of the highest one.

See the following code for the approach that I followed..:

```
//find the height of the pane based on the contents that is to go into them. This will
//count the number of newlines in the both the strings and will return the maximum.
//For eg if string 1 contains 3 newline chars and string 2 contains 5 chars the
//function will return 5.

int height= findheight(String str1,String str2);

JEditorPane pane1= new JEditorPane();
JEditorPane pane2= new JEditorPane();

pane1.setText(str1);  
pane2.setText(str2);

pane1.setSize(new Dimension((int) pane1.getPreferredSize().getWidth(),16*height));
pane2.setSize(new Dimension((int) pane2.getPreferredSize().getWidth(),16*height));
```

The value 16 in the above code is for a lets say a `x` font having font size `y`, if we change the font or font size the display will not fit. Is there a workaround or is there an inbuilt function that determines the height needed?

Comment: Take a look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

Comment: Do you mean like seen in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ8cx.png)?  And one scroll bar scrolls both editor panes?

Comment: got the answer..!! pane.getFont().getSize() will give the height of the text. add a bit of padding and you will get the height needed for a line
@madProgrammer, StanislavL: Both of you are right as well..I see lots of solutions to the problem.

Comment: No, it won't, or at least not for what you are trying to do.  `Font#getSize` returns the POINT size, not the pixel size a character will be rendered at on the screen, there is a difference, add in styling and it can change...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You are right..i decided to go with StanislavL's solution, which involved setting the text value in a dummy editorpane and getting its height from its preferred size. Seems to come up good in the UI, JFYI...my code also worked with getSize() after adding a padding, but i decided to stick with the other implementation as it will be a more 'generic' way for my code